Is it possible to overlay image on background with linear gradients such that the image fades into the background?
I have a div as follows:

Which has the styles in React:
background:
      linear-gradient(to right, #e0452c, 95%, white),
      linear-gradient(to top, #e0452c, 95%, white),
      linear-gradient(to bottom, #e0452c, 95%, white)`,
    backgroundBlendMode: "screen"

I have another image as follows:

Is it possible using CSS to achieve the following effect (which I made using Photoshop) where the edges of the images blur into the background or become transparent? If yes, then please tell me how I could do it.


Not really, but if you have Photoshop you could just cut out the person from the background and have a transparent background to your image....simples!
